# Capitalize the first letter of string in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, uppercase, capitalize

I want capitalize first character of string in angularjs

As i used `{{ uppercase_expression | uppercase}}` it convert whole string to upper case.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to write some code. Angular won't do *everything* for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Comment: This can be done using CSS also.. Check out the   text-transform: capitalize property

Comment: You can use this solution if you really want to use angular : http://codepen.io/WinterJoey/pen/sfFaK

Comment: create a simple directive/filter that will make first letter of word capital for you...

Answer (score 236, accepted):

use this capitalize filter

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.msg = 'hello, world.';
});

app.filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return (angular.isString(input) && input.length > 0) ? input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1).toLowerCase() : input;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <p><b>My Text:</b> {{msg | capitalize}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You get an error if you want to capitalize a number accidentally. The body of the function should be this: `return (angular.isString(s) && s.length > 0) ? s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substr(1).toLowerCase() : s;` . If it's not a string then return it unchanged.

Comment: Here is written the custom capitalization filter https://codepen.io/WinterJoey/pen/sfFaK

Answer (score 159):

I'd say don't use angular/js as you can simply use css instead:

In your css, add the class:

```
.capitalize {
   text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Then, simply wrap the expression (for ex) in your html:

```
<span class="capitalize">{{ uppercase_expression }}</span>
```

No js needed ;)

Comment: This transform will capitalize ***First Letter Of Each Word*** so is only applicable to one-word strings

Comment: @jakub.g If your just want to capitalize the first word (well, letter), simply expland the css selector with the `:first-letter` pseudo-element selector. Anything else left uncovered? :)

Comment: @Philzen Yes ! How would you do it with html only ? ;-)

Comment: @RomainVincent What do you mean by "HTML only"? Maybe my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207272/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-angularjs/39113339#39113339) helps (just click "Run code snippet" to see it in action). HTML content is static, you will at least need  to throw in some CSS or JS to modify its styling, respectively DOM content.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a bad attempt at making a joke.

Comment: This is generally a good idea, but if I want to process the capitalized string any further with Angular, JavaScript/Angular would still treat it as a non-capitalized string.

Answer (score 60):

If you use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), you can simply add the [`text-capitalize`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-transform) helper class:

```
<p class="text-capitalize">CapiTaliZed text.</p>
```

EDIT: just in case the link dies again:

> **Text Transform**
>
> Transform text in components with text capitalization classes.
>
> lowercased text.
>   UPPERCASED TEXT.
>   CapiTaliZed Text.
>
> ```html
> <p class="text-lowercase">Lowercased text.</p>
> <p class="text-uppercase">Uppercased text.</p>
> <p class="text-capitalize">CapiTaliZed text.</p>
> ```
>
> Note how text-capitalize only changes the first letter of each word, leaving the case of any other letters unaffected.

Comment: Quick and easy way to achieve the goal, also this capitalises first letter of every word in the string, which is cool.

Comment: behind the scenes this is just using `text-transform: capitalize;`

Answer (score 31):

If you are using Angular 4+ then you can just use `titlecase`

```
{{toUppercase | titlecase}}
```

don't have to write any pipes.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer—the question asks to capitalise the first letter of the string, not the first letter of every word.

Answer (score 24):

a nicer way

```
app.filter('capitalize', function() {
  return function(token) {
      return token.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + token.slice(1);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 20):

I like the answer from @TrampGuy

CSS is always (well, not always) a better choice, so: `text-transform: capitalize;` is certainly the way to go.

But what if your content is all uppercase to begin with?  If you try `text-transform: capitalize;` on content like "FOO BAR" you'll still get "FOO BAR" in your display.  To get around that issue you could put the `text-transform: capitalize;` in your css, but also lowercase your string, so:

```
<ul>
  <li class="capitalize">{{ foo.awesome_property | lowercase }}</li>
</ul>
```

where we are using @TrampGuy's capitalize class:

```
.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

So, pretending that `foo.awsome_property` would normally print "FOO BAR", it will now print the desired "Foo Bar".

Answer (score 18):

If you are after performance, try to avoid using AngularJS filters as they are applied twice per each expression to check for their stability.

A better way would be to use CSS `::first-letter` pseudo-element with `text-transform: uppercase;`. That can't be used on inline elements such as `span`, though, so the next best thing would be to use `text-transform: capitalize;` on the whole block, which capitalizes every word.

Example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.msg = 'hello, world.';
});
```

```css
.capitalize {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.capitalize::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.capitalize2 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <b>My text:</b> <div class="capitalize">{{msg}}</div>
        <p><b>My text:</b> <span class="capitalize2">{{msg}}</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately `::first-letter` doesn't work on `display: inline` or `display: flex`, only on `display:block` or `inline-block` elements

Answer (score 14):

if you want capitalize each word from string (in progress -> In Progress), you can use array like this.

```
.filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return (!!input) ? input.split(' ').map(function(wrd){return wrd.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + wrd.substr(1).toLowerCase();}).join(' ') : '';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13):

This is another way:

```
{{some_str | limitTo:1 | uppercase}}{{some_str.substr(1) | lowercase }}
```

Answer (score 9):

For Angular 2 and up, you can use `{{ abc | titlecase }}`.

Check [Angular.io API](https://angular.io/api) for complete list.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer—the question asks to capitalise the first letter of the string, not the first letter of every word.

Answer (score 7):

```css
.capitalize {
  display: inline-block;
}

.capitalize:first-letter {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<span class="capitalize">
  really, once upon a time there was a badly formatted output coming from my backend, <strong>all completely in lowercase</strong> and thus not quite as fancy-looking as could be - but then cascading style sheets (which we all know are <a href="http://9gag.com/gag/6709/css-is-awesome">awesome</a>) with modern pseudo selectors came around to the rescue...
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

In angular 7+ which has built-in [pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe)

```
{{ yourText | titlecase  }}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the AngularJS from meanjs.org, I place the custom filters in `modules/core/client/app/init.js`

I needed a custom filter to capitalize each word in a sentence, here is how I do so:

```
angular.module(ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName).filter('capitalize', function() {
return function(str) {
    return str.split(" ").map(function(input){return (!!input) ? input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1).toLowerCase() :         ''}).join(" ");

}
});
```

The credit of the map function goes to @Naveen raj

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to build custom filter then  you can use directly

```
{{ foo.awesome_property.substring(0,1) | uppercase}}{{foo.awesome_property.substring(1)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.filter('capitalize', function() {
    return function(str) {
        if (str === undefined) return; // avoid undefined
        str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        var c = '';
        for (var i = 0; i <= (str.length - 1); i++) {
            var word = ' ';
            for (var j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
                c = str[i][j];
                if (j === 0) {
                    c = c.toUpperCase();
                }
                word += c;
            }
            str[i] = word;
        }
        str = str.join('');
        return str;
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my own take on this issue, I would use a custom directive myself;

```
app.directive('capitalization', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

            var transformedInput = (!!inputValue) ? inputValue.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputValue.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';

            if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                modelCtrl.$render();
            }

            return transformedInput;
        });
    }
};
```

Once declared you can place inside your Html as below;

```
<input ng-model="surname" ng-trim="false" capitalization>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead if you want to capitalize each word of a sentence then you can use this code

```
app.filter('capitalize', function() {


return function(input, scope) {
if (input!=null)
input = input.toLowerCase().split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
   // You do not need to check if i is larger than input length, as your for does that for you
   // Assign it back to the array
   input[i] = input[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input[i].substring(1);     


}
   // Directly return the joined string
   return input.join(' '); 
  }
});
```

and just add filter "capitalize" to your string input, for ex - {{name | capitalize}}

Answer (score 0):

in Angular 4 or CLI you can create a PIPE like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'capitalize'
})
/**
 * Place the first letter of each word in capital letters and the other in lower case. Ex: The LORO speaks = The Loro Speaks
 */
export class CapitalizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
    value = value.replace('  ', ' ');
    if (value) {
      let w = '';
      if (value.split(' ').length > 0) {
        value.split(' ').forEach(word => {
          w += word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.toString().substr(1, word.length).toLowerCase() + ' '
        });
      } else {
        w = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.toString().substr(1, value.length).toLowerCase();
      }
      return w;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has 'titlecase' which capitalizes the first letter in a string

For ex:

```
envName | titlecase
```

will be displayed as  EnvName

When used with interpolation, avoid all spaces like

```
{{envName|titlecase}}
```

and the first letter of value of envName will be printed in upper case.

Comment: This does not provide any value to the answer above

Comment: This is an incorrect answer—the question asks to capitalise the first letter of the string, not the first letter of every word.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value){
  value = (value.length > 1) ? value[0].toUpperCase() + value.substr(1).toLowerCase() : value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split your String into two parts and manage their case separately.

```
{{ (Name.charAt(0) | uppercase) + "" + (Name.slice(1, element.length) | lowercase) }}
```

or

```
{{ Name.charAt(0) | uppercase }} {{ Name.slice(1, element.length) | lowercase  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ uppercase_expression.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() +  uppercase_expression.substr(1) }}

Answer (score -1):

You can add capitalize functionality run time as:

```
<td>{{lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ lastName.substr(1).toLowerCase()}}</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

`{{ uppercase_expression | capitaliseFirst}}` should work