# Alternative way to apply dynamic data to title attribute

Tags: html, angularjs, lodash

I am trying to set dynamic data as title to label tag. I have used capitalize property from lodash and applied it something like this `<label title="{{caption}} {{optVal.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+optVal.slice(1)}}">{{optVal}}</label>` .I realized there's too much of calculation happening on the DOM object which is bad practice, later I tried to pass it to a function where it could return the needed result. I am still looking for a better solution to reduce the overhead, can someone help me with this.

http://jsbin.com/cexonihaki/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Why don't you use css to capitalize. CSS property text-transform: capitalize;

Comment: yes @joashp is right, you can use css for this, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207272/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-angularjs

Comment: He cannot uppercase only a letter and left the other word as it with text-transform

Comment: joashp@ I cannot use css capitalize property as I am applying change only to title and not displaying it anywhere else, the other option is to apply filter.

Comment: Shubham Takode@ Your suggestion actually gave a solution to me, I am still not sure if it's the ideal solution or not but still thanks for the reference :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in your scope who create the title and use it in the view ( or use CSS as other mention it but it will uppercase all the title and not only a letter )

I cloned your jsbin, http://jsbin.com/vutuwibube/1/edit?html,js,output
it run instantly

```
 <label ng-attr-title="{{creatTitle()}}">{{optVal}}</label>
```

Controller side :

```
 $scope.creatTitle = function( ){
      return $scope.caption + " " + $scope.optVal.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ $scope.optVal.slice(1);
 }
```

Comment: AlainIb@ I had tried this as well, but still looking for a better solution

Comment: I tried ;) you have three posibilities. 1) do the concat in the view as you do, 2) do the concat in controller as i do 3) use CSS but cannot make only a letter uppercased

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$timeout()` function or  `scope.$digest();`

here is the angular [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest). for digest

thats the nice [documentation](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) for differences between them

Comment: why to use $timeout or $digest ? timeout is for delaying a call . maybe you want to say $apply. Anyway i think both is useless her

Comment: oh yes I'm thinking about alternative way for $scope.$apply.