# Capitalize first letter of a string using Angular or typescript

Tags: angular, capitalize

How can I capitalize the first letter of a string using Angular or typescript?

Comment: Check this [reference links][blog]. There will be solution. [blog]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207272/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-angularjs

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Pipes are the correct angular way to do this

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is an Angular question, not a javascript one. A custom pipe should be used, which does not exist in regular javascript.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```js
function titleCaseWord(word: string) {
  if (!word) return word;
  return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

You can also use in template **TitleCasePipe**

Some component template:

```js
{{value |titlecase}}
```

Comment: Note that the `TitleCasePipe` will capitalise the first letter of **every word** in the string, not just the first letter of the entire string—so the `TitleCasePipe` is not strictly an option for what has been asked.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Like Alex mentioned, TitleCasePipe will capitalize very word. Answers below should be accepted. Alternative is a custom pipe.

Comment: ⚠️ Be carful with this solution, because in some languages (like Spanish) when you have a question string, start with character `¿Esto es una pregunta?`. So, when apply this algorithm in spanish questions, don't work properly.
I add this:
```if (value[0] === '¡' || value[0] === '¿') {
    return (
        value[0] +
        value[1].toUpperCase() +
        value.substr(2).toLowerCase()
    );
}```

Comment: @MatiasdeAndrea I wonder if `toLocaleUpperCase()` would help here

Comment: Is a nice question @MichaelMurphy. I don't test this

Comment: @MatiasdeAndrea I think the answer is no, using `toLocaleUpperCase()` won't help (I did some quick testing). I think the best option is something like what you have stated, but with a function `isPunctuation(char)` that takes in a single character string and returns `true` if the character is accepted punctuation, otherwise `false`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because validly capitalized letters not at the beginning of the word will be made lowercase. For example, the hyphenated last name "Jones-Smith" will transform as "Jones-smith" .... see examples at docs e.g. https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe

Comment: You need to make custom pipe, example:


`import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'firstLetterCapital'
})
export class FirstLetterCapitalPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(sentence: string, ...args: unknown[]): string {
    return sentence[0].toUpperCase() + sentence.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }

}`

Comment: ⚠️ this is not a good solution because titlecase pipe will capitilise every world in the sentence

Answer (score 21):

```js
let str: string = 'hello';
str = str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = 'santosh';
str = str ? str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made, such as languages with which it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Yes Sure, Thanks for your advice